# ef group by columns order issue?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, group-by

Ok, imagine that I have EF 6.1.3 and database first model (stored in edmx file) that contains an entity named Product.
That entity have 4 columns, for example: Id (int), Name {string), Code (string), Rank (int). The columns are stored in that order as I described and you can see that in a model browser.
Then i'm writing a query like this:

```
var list = mycontext.Products
   .Where(x => x.Id < 10)
   .GroupBy(x => new { x.Code, x.Name })
   .Select(x=> new { x.Key.Code, x.Key.Name, MaxRank = x.Max(z => z.Rank) })
   .ToList();
```

As you can see, I used an another columns order in my group by clause (Code column, then Name column).

But in SQL query I have such query text:

```
....
GROUP BY
        [Extent1].[Name]
      , [Extent1].[Code]
....
```

The columns in group by clause always ordered in same order which they have in a edmx file.

It just a sample, but that situation always break my query plans, cause sql starting to use wrong indexes and etc.

Anybody know how can I fix that?

[without sort](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Br9hS.png)
[with sort](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Ljwz.png)

Comment: Have you tried changing the order?

Comment: Add a `.OrderBy` to the code. See if that works. Or you can order the `list` after the fact.

Comment: Do you mean that SQL Server will build different query plans for 2 identical queries with only difference in order of members in group by clause???

Comment: @JacobH, yes, if i changed the columns order in model browser, for example, change, code and name, that will generate normal query when i use .GroupBy(x => new { x.Code, x.Name }), but it chnges columns order if u use .GroupBy(x => new { x.Name, x.Code })

Comment: @WEI_DBA, i do not trying obtain the ordered result set, i'm just trying get a query with group by clause which contains a columns order as i used in linq query

Comment: Oh you want the column *positions* to change, not the order. ORDER is an actual SQL command that changes the order of the data returned. What is stopping you from changing the SQL query to match your code?

Comment: @sepupic, in that example it does not matter, but if i have more complicated query-then yes. 
TableA: A_KEY, A2, A3, A4
TableB: B_KEY, A_KEY, B1, B2
IX_A on TableA A2, A3, A_KEY includes A4 
IX_B on TableB A_KEY, B_KEY, B1 includes B2
SELECT A.A2, A.A3, A.A_KEY, B.B_KEY, B.B1, SUM(B.B2)
FROM TableA A
INNER JOIN TableB B ON A.A_KEY = B.A_KEY
WHERE A .A2 = 'some value' AND A.A3 = 'another value' 
GROUP BY A.A2, A.A3, A.A_KEY, B.B_KEY, B.B1
will have only 2 index seek and join without any sorting. 
If we change GROUP BY clasue columns order, we will have a sorting.

Comment: @JacobH, maybe my english isn't very good, but yes, i'm talking about columns positions in GROUP BY clause which is generated by EF. As i said in my post: EF generate GROUP BY clause with ignoring columns positions writed in linq query and changed it in accordance with positions stored in EDMX file

Comment: you can put the columns in group by clause in any order you want, the plan will not change

Comment: @sepupic, i added two screenshots to my post

Comment: Yes, I was wrong, thank you for your example